# I want to execute something after rendering the DOM tree

Tags: javascript

## I want to execute something after rendering the DOM tree.

I'm trying to build an app by using canvas.
In this process,

I try to do below.

```
getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

But there is nothing.

If I surround my code with this.

```
setTimeout(...,0)
```

It will work.

I think it is caused by rendering.
How to execute after render?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.body.onload = function() {
  var canvas = getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
  // do something with canvas
}
```